# Android App Crashing in some Devices Only, most of them Huawei

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

My App is working fine on almost all devices, but some customer giving reply as App not Opening Crashing like that. I never seen a real device crashing on the same App. Play store showing some crash reports and it include almost all type of device models but most of them were huawei devices..

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at www.ourshopee.com.fragment.TabDealOfDayFragment$2.onResponse (TabDealOfDayFragment.java:189)
  at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run (ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:65)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6940)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

I am getting this Error in play console, but i working in all my testing device.

```
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0-RC1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.0-RC1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
```

Please Help me, your Help will be Appreciated..

TabDealFragment

```
 private void getProductsFromServer() {

        if (AppUtils.isConnectedToInternet(getContext(), true)) {
            llErrorLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            Callback<DealOfDayResponse> callback = new Callback<DealOfDayResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<DealOfDayResponse> response) {


                    progress_deals.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    if (response.body().getCode()==200) {


                        if (response.body().getData().getTempSection().size() != 0) {
                            dealOfDayList.addAll(response.body().getData().getTempSection());
                            dealproductListingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        dealOfDayList.addAll(response.body().getData().getDealOfDay());
                        dealproductListingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        llErrorLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        tvErrorText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        loading = true;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                 Log.d("Whats_My_Crash", String.valueOf(t));


                    progress_deals.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    llErrorLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tvErrorText.setText(getString(R.string.err_unexpected));
                }
            };
            ApiManager.getApi().getService().getDealOfDayProducts(Constants.GET_DEALS_PRODUCTS, AppUtils.getCountryCode(getContext()), page, SUBCATEGORY_ID, BRAND_ID).enqueue(callback);
            loading = true;
        } else {
            llErrorLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvErrorText.setText(getString(R.string.err_internet));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the `TabDealOfDayFragment ` or at least the parts of that.

Comment: My App not Crashing , so i am not able find whats the issue,..https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=www.ourshopee.com

Comment: At Line 189 you access an object and it is null... No idea which line is #189 as we can't see line numbers here.

Comment: Do you somehow stop the request/callback when your app is put to background before the request comes back from the server?

Comment: in same response i am adding 2 Array Response in same recyclerview

Comment: I'm guessing either `getTempSection()` or `getDealOfDay()` returns null. Is there a possibility that either of the fields can return null from the server? If not, is there a possibility that the data itself can return empty or null? I mean the chained call with what you call as `getData()` or `response.body()`.

Comment: Or just tell us what line 189 is. In this code we can't see line numbers.

Comment: if (response.body().getData().getTempSection().size() != 0) {
                            dealOfDayList.addAll(response.body().getData().getTempSection());
                            dealproductListingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

Comment: Furkan bro , the why only getting Error in some devices only'

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of the line there are two possibilities:

Either your backend returns a response that does not have any temp sections inside the body or that the complete body / data is empty and therefore returned as null by retrofit.

As `body()` can already return `null` you should improve your error handling and check if body is null, than if data returns null and finally if `getTempSection()` returns null.

The reasons for that are transparent for us. We do not know your backend and your data structure or API definition but you should always consider to deal with the absence of data without crashing.

Comment: There is no issue with Api Always geting Array size >0 . but the problem is its working Almost All devices

Comment: geting Error in some devices only

Comment: `There is no issue with Api Always geting Array size >0` well, the crashes you are getting state that this is not the case. So you better stop saying "not an issue" and start dealing with this case

Comment: if (response.body().getCode() == 200) {
                        if (response.body().getData().getTempSection().size() > 0) {
                            dealOfDayList.addAll(response.body().getData().getTempSection());
                            dealproductListingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        if (response.body().getData().getDealOfDay().size() > 0) {

            dealOfDayList.addAll(response.body().getData().getDealOfDay());
                            dealproductListingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

Comment: Please don't drop multiple lines of code in a comment. Nobody can read that...

Comment: sorry ,, i put my answer below

Comment: and please update your dependencies. okhttp 3 is way outdated. Latest one is 4.3.1. Retrofit is 2.7.1...

Answer (score 0):

```
SomeType body = response.body()
if (body.getCode() == 200) {
    SomeData data = body.getData()
    List<TempSection> tempSections = data.getTempSection()
    if (tempSections.size() > 0) {
        dealOfDayList.addAll(tempSections);
        dealproductListingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    List<DealOfDay> dealsOfDay = data.getDealOfDay()
    if (dealsOfDay.size() > 0) {
        dealOfDayList.addAll(dealsOfDay);
        dealproductListingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a user of close to 2 years. Please do NOT just put some code as an answer. Explain what it does and how it solves your issue. Maybe you might want to check the [FAQ] again